# Esri.ArcGISRuntime nuget package is not supported for netcoreapp2.2

Tags: esri, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I'm trying to use the following classes `CredentialRequestInfo` and `Credential`.

And as mentioned in [ArcGIS Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/uwp/api-reference/html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Security_CredentialRequestInfo.htm), in order to use the classes we need to install `Esri.ArcGISRuntime` nuget package.

But when installing the package, I get the following error:

**`The 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime' nuget package is not supported for the Target Framework 'netcoreapp2.2'`**

Is there a work-around we can do in order to use this nuget package? Or is there any updates or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and talking with developers in `esri`. Found out that to use this nuget package I have to use .net core 3.1.

`Esri.ArcGISRuntime` will not work with .net core 2.2.